# How to manage DNS in NetworkManager via console (nmcli)?

Tags: networking, centos7, nameserver, networkmanager

I have CentOS 7.2 (guest in VirtualBox, vagrant box `centos/7`, no GUI).

I see there is a nameserver in file:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

But how to add or replace with new one?

I have done this manually directly in the network:

```
$ vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
PEERDS=no
DNS1=8.8.4.4
DNS2=8.8.8.8
```

And it works.

But is there any way to do this through `nmcli`?

P.S. No `nmtui` installed (in a selected system).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here is the command to modify an existing connection.

```
nmcli con mod "$connectionName" ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

`connectionName` can be found by command: `nmcli con`. In the question case, it will be `"System eth0"`

If you want to ignore automatically configured nameservers and search domains, ie the settings passed from DHCP.

```
nmcli con mod "$connectionName" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

Finally, to enable the changes, <s>bring the connection down then up:</s>

```
nmcli con down "$connectionName"
nmcli con up "$connectionName"
```

restart the NetworkManager service (if you don't want be disconnected) :

```
service NetworkManager restart
```

Verify with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. You should not edit `/etc/resolv.conf` manually as it is generated by NetworkManager service, it is likely to get overridden at any given time.

[Useful nmcli manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-network_bridging_using_the_networkmanager_command_line_tool_nmcli)

Comment: Yeah, thx, found it already. A bit edited your answer...  But how to replace exist nameserver?

Comment: there is "+ipv4.dns" and "ipv4.dns" can be used, but second one (without "+") doesn't replace.

Comment: I'd rather use nmtui or if possible the GUI version as well. There is no need to be a command line ninja, if you have a more convenient option which is doing the same thing.

Comment: @lauc.exon.nod Some options aren't available in nmtui, and you have to use nmcli to get at them.

Comment: Link is dead....

Comment: This only works for a specific connection. Is there a way to do it for a device instead? For example, on a laptop, I change networks frequently and don't want to update this for every connection.

Comment: To remove the default ipv4 dns from a device, try "nmcli device mod <<device>> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes".

Comment: Actually you should be able to do "nmcli c down <interface>; nmcli c up <interface>" on the same line with the semi-colon separator, it will work 99% of the time. The shell will run them in the same session.  Obviously if you type them on different lines, the shell won't get that "up" command after downed the interface.

Answer (score 12):

there is good TUI tool developed by red hat named `nmtui` that you really should try. it is pre-installed on various distros, nowadays, but if it is not on yours, try:

```
  sudo yum install networkmanager-tui
```

it uses a curses based text interface - accessible from the command line. `nmcli` is only especially necessary when writing scripts, and has larger room for error due to the larger variety of possible input.

Comment: I cannot use it until set up new dns, because there is no Internet connection. Anyway, thanks for this point.

Comment: it is included in various distros, nowadays

Comment: Possibly so. I just didn't have it my docker container.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to setting the ipv4.dns property described above...

To exclude the DHCP provided DNS servers...set the ipv4.ignore-auto-dns property to yes.

```
nmcli con mod <connectionName> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

To enable the changes, bring the connection down then up:

```
nmcli con down <connectionName>
nmcli con up <connectionName>
```

Verify with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case I have done a little script to do that automatically (here with google DNS) for every ethernet/wireless connections:

```
nmcli -g name,type connection  show  --active | awk -F: '/ethernet|wireless/ { print $1 }' | while read connection
do
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
  nmcli con mod "$connection" ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
  nmcli con down "$connection" && nmcli con up "$connection"
done
```

At the end, the wireless connections will be lost. You have to reconnect and voilà !